# Div + float: как растянуть div по высоте?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать таблицу из 2 колонок при помощи CSS:

```
<div style="display: block; padding: 5px 0px; width: 400px; clear: both;">
<div style="width: 200px; float: left;">
Несколько слов, которые растягиваются на 2 строки: </div>
<div style="display: block; width: 200px; float: left;">
45</div>
</div>
<label style="display: block; padding: 5px 0px; width: 400px; clear: both;">
...
</label>
...
```

Поскольку строкой таблицы может выступать как и `div`, так и `label` — поэтому `display: block;` (HTML генерируется из скрипта). На первый взгляд, отображается все так, как задумывалось, но просмотрев код в редакторе Google Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+i) обнаружил, что тег задающий строку (`style="display: block; padding: 5px 0px; width: 400px; clear: both;"`) по высоте занимает только 10 точек, т.е. ячейки таблицы как-бы выпирают из строки.

Подскажите, как растянуть тег-строку таблицы по ширине наполнения?

Answer (score 2):

блоки с `float`-ом не влияют на блоки без. Лучше сделай в `<div style="display: block; padding: 5px 0px; width: 400px; clear: both;">` вместо `clear: both;` напиши `overflow: hidden;`. Твою проблему решит 100%.

Comment: Спасибо, да, проблема решена, хотя совсем не понятно, почему помог overflow - буду разбираться.